# pip install PyAudio

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, package

I am trying to install some packages in Python and when I try to run the command

pip install PyAudio

this error show up:

Collecting PyAudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for PyAudio did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
running install
c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\romanticalexa\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip
and other standards-based tools.
setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\user\pycharmpr
ojects\romanticalexa\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftware
Foundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Window
s Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> PyAudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: Install `wheel` first with `python3 -m pip install wheel`. PyAudio has native components written in C that need compilation. It seems like you don't have a C compiler available. `wheel` allows you to install precompiled python packages so you'll be able to bypass compilation.

Comment: I think you can read this and install what this post says:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html

Comment: I installed it with python -m pip install wheel, since python3 was not recognized....anyway, I wrote two other commands before:                                        
  pip install pipwin
                                                                pipwin install pyaudio                                                          , since it says they were successfully installed, I suppose I have pyaudio now